# new com.provider.JSSEProvider() Cannot resolve symbole provider

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android, I was following a tutorial on how to send an Email using JavaMail API, I have add the necessary Jars properly but I always face the Cannot resolve symbol provider on the GmailSender Class, I tried removing and adding the jars but the problem still persist.

```
  static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());
    }
```

am I missing something ? i am working on androidStudio by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer isn't incorrect, just not very straightforward... so let me elaborate on what Sharath is saying.

```
Assume for a moment that your package name is "com.mycompany.projectname"
```

Change this:

```
  static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());
  }
```

To this:

```
  static {
    Security.addProvider(new com.mycompany.projectname.JSSEProvider());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same problem.
We have to add our package in there.
Just copy package on the top of your class.
Like package com.myapplication3.JSSEProvider();
Hope it helps!